# How to get items for logged in user ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to show booking of logged in user from database, but its show all data from all user. this is the original code:

```
// GET: Bookings
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var bookings = db.Bookings.Include(b => b.Room).Include(b => b.Register);
   return View(bookings.ToList());
}
```

Here what I have tried but the output show an error,

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var bookings = db.Bookings.Include(b => b.Room).Include(b => b.Register == Session["id"]);
   return View(bookings.ToList());
}
```

This is the user table in the database, so if I login as user no.1, the booking data should display only customerID no.1, but the problem is, the data show all user bookings.

[image]

Here is the image of booking db, 
[image]

Here is the code for login:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(Register login)
{
    using (HotelBookingEntities db = new HotelBookingEntities())
    {
        var userDetails = db.Registers.Where(x => x.email == login.email && x.password == login.password).FirstOrDefault();

        if (userDetails == null)
        {
            ViewBag.WrongMessage = "Wrong username or password";
            return View("Login", login);
        }
        else
        {
           Session["id"] = userDetails.id;
           Session["username"] = userDetails.username;
           return RedirectToAction("Index", "Rooms");
        }
    }      
}
```

Comment: Add your model classes please! Also explain more details what are you expecting?

Comment: @TanvirArjel pls see my latest question, i already edit it

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know whether it works for you or not!

Comment: In your GET action, get the current UserId(We do not know how you are storing it and how to retrieve it) and add a where condition to your LINQ query to get data for that specific user. You can use the `Where` method. Ex : `db.Bookings.Where(a=>a.CustomerID==userId)`

Comment: @Shyju i already update the code for login part, see my update question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as follows:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    int userId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"]);
    var bookings = db.Bookings.Where.Include(b => b.Room).Where(b => b.CustomerID == userId).ToList();

    return View(bookings);
}
```

Comment: Problem is in your code! Can you give me remote access to check whether you have written everything properly.

Comment: May be problem is in the `Session["id"]`. How have you set the value `id` in session?

Comment: i already update the code for login part for session, see my update question

Comment: @Much Now its not working? If not then what's error message is it showing?

Comment: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'object',  so i add,  int userID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"]); and its working

Comment: Updated my answer!

Comment: Grear to hear that it has worked for you! Thank you.

Comment: Thanks you for your ideas!